# Custom math with aggregation using mongo and angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using aggregation to display registration teams and nets for a stats page.  I can do the count on each level, but the calculations for nets is inaccurate.  My aggregation is as follows:

```
module.exports.registrationStats = function(req, res) {
  Registration.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$day", 
                "group": "$group",
                "division": "$division",
                "level": "$level"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day", 
                "group": "$_id.group",
                "division": "$_id.division"                
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
            "levels": {
                "$push": {
                    "level": "$_id.level",
                    "teams": "$count",
                    "nets" : {$ceil : { $divide: [ "$count" , 5 ] } }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day", 
                "group": "$_id.group"             
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
            "divisions": {
                "$push": {
                    "division": "$_id.division",
                    "count": "$count",
                    "levels": "$levels"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, regStats){
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error grouping registrations");
      res.status(500).json(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Found and grouped " + regStats.length + " regStats");
      res.json(regStats);
    }
  });
};
```

This gives me the following as an output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": "Saturday",
            "group": "nonpro"
        },
        "count": 144,
        "divisions": [
            {
                "division": "Men's",
                "count": 69,
                "levels": [
                    {
                        "level": "BB",
                        "teams": 30,
                        "nets": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "level": "A",
                        "teams": 8,
                        "nets": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "level": "B",
                        "teams": 19,
                        "nets": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "level": "AA",
                        "teams": 12,
                        "nets": 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "division": "Women's",
                "count": 75,
                "levels": [
                    {
                        "level": "AA",
                        "teams": 9,
                        "nets": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "level": "BB",
                        "teams": 16,
                        "nets": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "level": "B",
                        "teams": 18,
                        "nets": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "level": "A",
                        "teams": 32,
                        "nets": 7
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem is that I cannot just run a ceil filter on the Math.ceil(divisions.count/5) to get a value for divisions.nets or Math.ceil(_id.count/5) to get _id.nets because they are wrong in some cases.

I need to be able to total divisions.levels.nets and push that into divisions.nets and add divisions.nets and put that value into _id.nets so the calculations work properly.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Add `$project` stage to calculate the `nets` for `level` followed by `$sum` & `$push` `nets` for rest of `$groups`

```
Registration.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$day", 
                "group": "$group",
                "division": "$division",
                "level": "$level"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { $project: { count:1,  nets: { $ceil : { $divide: [ "$count" , 5 ] } } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day", 
                "group": "$_id.group",
                "division": "$_id.division"                
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
            "nets": { "$sum": "$nets" },
            "levels": {
                "$push": {
                    "level": "$_id.level",
                    "teams": "$count",
                    "nets" : "$nets"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day", 
                "group": "$_id.group"             
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
            "nets": { "$sum": "$nets" },
            "divisions": {
                "$push": {
                    "division": "$_id.division",
                    "count": "$count",
                    "nets:": "$nets",
                    "levels": "$levels"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Okay, that's awesome!  So, project allows me to take something from the first grouping and use it in the second part.  Then I can "project" or place that into the other levels of grouping?  All I've seen about aggregation seems to refer to unix or something I have no idea about, so I was kinda lost.

Comment: You can add additional/overwrite fields on each document using `$project/$addFields`.